# browser retrieve facebook credentials from facebook app

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, wep

I'm developing a web-app that at the start connect to facebook, but before asking user credentials I'd like to try to retrieve these credentials from official Facebook Application (Android, IOS or MAC app).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The user must accept the applications permissions BEFORE anything is displayed.
The easiest way is just printing their details from them to view once they're signed in, but following Facebook's Guidelines, you can't view a user's profile information without.

Comment: I know that user must accept the applications permission, and I know that for do this I follow the guide on Facebook developer, but is not what I want.

Comment: I'm not too sure what it is that you're requesting then, can you elaborate more please?

Comment: I'd like that browser app installed on smartphone ask to Facebook App (install on smartphone) the credentials to connect to facebook.